# With Actions on Google, what is the recommended way to get the user's country with coarse location information?

Tags: actions-on-google

The [getDeviceLocation()](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/AssistantApp#getDeviceLocation) call may return either lat/lon coordinates if the surface provides precise location information or a ZIP code and a city for coarse location information.

With the former one can use the Google Maps API to reverse-geocode the coordinates, the latter, however, can be ambiguous as there is no country information provided. Is there a recommended way to disambiguate the device location if only coarse permissions are provided?

For a more concrete example:

```
const requestedPermission = app.data.requestedPermission;
const permissions = app.SupportedPermissions;
if (requestedPermission === permissions.DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION) {
  // Not available! We've only got .zipCode and .city.
  const countryCode = app.getDeviceLocation().countryCode;
  doSomethingBasedOnCountry(countryCode);
}
if (requestedPermission === permissions.DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION) {
  const { coordinates } = app.getDeviceLocation();
  return coordinatesToCountryCode(mapsClient, coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude)
    .then(doSomethingBasedOnCountry);
}
```

Comment: Why the `firebase` tag?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It's irrelevant for this question.

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at the locale information that is in the request? Do you think that will help you?

[image]

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest#user
https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/6597aa2dd3c75579a667837b878b448651515714/assistant-app.js#L1444

Comment: There is absolutely no guarantee that the user is actually from the country in the locale tag. Many languages aren't supported yet by the Assistant and most people will default to the en-US locale if their language isn't supported.